# Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, random-walk

Suppose we have a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as seen on the picture below. We can walk to north, west, south and east each with probability of $\frac{1}{4}$

[image]

Now we start at point 3 and we want to know the probability of leaving the set $\{1,2,3\}$ in north or east direction. My idea was to assign to each vertex the probability and solve it a system of linear equation systems.[image]

$\omega(x)=\text{probability of leaving the set \{1,2,3\} in north or east direction}$

Note that $\omega(x)=1:x\in \{10,6,4\}$ because these are the vertices where we leave the set $\{1,2,3\}$ in north and east direction and $\omega(y)=0:y\in \{9,8,7,5\}$ because these are the vertices where we leave at south or west.

$$\omega(3)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\omega(6)}_{=1}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\omega(4)}_{=1}+\frac{1}{4}\omega(1)+\frac{1}{4}\omega(5)$$
$$\omega(1)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\omega(8)}_{=0}+\frac{1}{4}\omega(2)+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\omega(7)}_{=0}+\frac{1}{4}\omega(3)$$
$$\omega(2)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\omega(10)}_{=1}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\omega(9)}_{=0}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\omega(6)}_{=1}+\frac{1}{4}\omega(1)$$

If we solve this system of linear equations we get

$\omega(3)=\frac{4}{7}$,
$\omega(1)=\frac{2}{7}$,
$\omega(2)=\frac{4}{7}$

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Yes, though your curly brackets are a bit wide.  It is $\omega(6)=1$ rather than $\frac14 \omega(6)=1$

Comment: By symmetry you have $\omega(2)=\omega(3)$ and so you can reduce your equations to $\omega(3)=\frac14\omega(1)+\frac12$ and $\omega(1)=\frac12\omega(3)$ to get your result